# Return PowerShell Command result in batch file

Tags: batch, powershell

I have a powershell command that works pretty well in returning the date i want in the format I need. I have been unable to call this command in a batch file to be used in a separate script.

C:\Users\xxx>powershell -command (get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -uformat "
%Y%m%d")
20171115

This appears to work although the date format isnt what I would like for it to be:

```
set "psCommand=powershell -command "(get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)))""
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%psCommand%') do set "leaf=%%I"
echo %leaf% >> uploadsp.txt
```

Output is: Wednesday, November 15, 2017 5:19:34 PM

Thanks

So I may have gotten ahead oh myself. This is what I had previously and I was merely trying to change it to get date-1.

```
echo @echo off > uploadsp.txt
set mydate=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
echo set mydate=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2% >> uploadsp.txt

set myfile=Epic_DSH360144_Drug_Utilization_%mydate%_DU.txt
echo put %myfile% >> uploadsp.txt
exit
```

Comment: Confusing question. first line says it returns the format you need. 4th sentence says it works but isn't correct format.  Which is correct?  Which format do you want?  And indeed, current script does work.

Comment: And you’re not running the same PowerShell command in both examples, The first one includes a `-uformat` option that is missing from the second.

Comment: That is correct, when I include the uformat the output changes from a date to a text depicting the powershell command. I only tried to do powershell to be able to determine date-1 after failing to do it in batch. I have posted my initial code. thanks

Comment: Let me know if the answer I provided helped resolve or not but likely the issue is with the `-format "%%Y%%m%%d` as I listed below whether or not you fix the logic you use with that syntax in the batch or use it the way I wrote it which is how I do most of my automated scripts like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work as expected as you describe by piping the **PowerShell** script logic within the batch script to a temp `PS1` file, and then using a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop to take the result of the executed **PowerShell** script to subtract the number of days from the current date within it, and save that result as a variable to use in the batch script for your needs (`%leaf%`) afterwards.

Please note I had to double up the percent signs in the **PowerShell** `-format "%%Y%%m%%d"` to ensure those symbols are used as literal characters and not special characters by the batch script.

> **Escaping Percents**
>
> The % character has a special meaning for command line parameters and
>   FOR parameters.
>
> To treat a percent as a regular character, double it:
>
> `%%`
>
> <sub>[Escape Characters, Delimiters and
>   Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)</sub>

---

### Batch Script

```
@ECHO ON

:DynamicPSScriptBuild
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmp%~n0.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"
ECHO get-date((get-date).addDays(-1)) -uformat "%%Y%%m%%d">>"%PSScript%"

FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%I IN ('Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"') DO SET "leaf=%%I"
echo %leaf% >> uploadsp.txt
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Answer (score 1):

As per all the help received here, the logic below seemed to work well for my particular needs:

```
For /F "delims=" %%G In ('PowerShell -Command "&{((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).ToString('yyyyMMdd')}"') Do Set "yesterday=%%G"    
For /F "delims=" %%Y In ('PowerShell -Command "&{((Get-Date).AddDays(-2)).ToString('yyyyMMdd')}"') Do Set "daybefore=%%Y"
```