# "dir like" sorted by time in a batch file (.bat) using a piped string command: Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime, not working

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm trying to build a trivial batch file in Windows for command line to execute a "dir like" command to list the directory contents sorted by time, avoiding typing:  `Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime` (this whole string works perfect).

My last try was this (`.dir.bat` [with a dot ahead to differentiate from regular `dir`]):

 `@echo on` 

 `Get-ChildItem ^| Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime`

After launching the `.dir.bat`:

```
C:\>Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime
"Get-ChildItem" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
executable program or batch file.
```

I think I tried almost everything. Even, as my last try shows, escaping the pipe `|` with `^|`
Using `start`, `echo`, quotes, parentheses, etc.

I read that batch interpretation takes `|` as an instantiation action, so this explains why former experiments launched a new `powershell/cmd` window instead of executing the wanted string command.

Comment: It seems you are running a PowerShell command from cmd or a batch script which won't work that way. There are answers on this post that answers how to accomplish this and a number of other answers on SU already as well: https://superuser.com/questions/1269124/return-powershell-command-result-in-batch-file/

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I will go and read this particular link you mention (as I read already others on topic, related, but still quite obscure for my level of confusion). Could you post the two cases in my particular case (if are possible in each shell)? 1. `Powershell` version. 2. `cmd` version? Because this would make me understand it and make quite a leap separating worlds that I am completely mixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the command is :

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime
```

Second, PowerShell scripts are run from `.ps1` files.
If you wish to run them from CMD/batch, use the
`powershell` command:

```
powershell "Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime"
```